# Invalid handle error from python3 ctypes - worked yesterday

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I have a script, and within it I need to call a function from a DLL for other software. The script ran yesterday and over the past several months, but stopped today. I did uninstall and reinstall python yesterday, since I was having other unrelated problems.

```
gmAPI = cdll.LoadLibrary(
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/GoldMine/gm7s32.dll")
recid = create_string_buffer(16)
gmAPI.GMW_NewRecID(recid, username)
```

This is the part of the code that's bugging, I'm getting error code 6, invalid handle when I try to execute the third line. It's a 32 bit dll and I'm running it on the same 32 bit interpreter, though reinstalled.

My cdll object appears like this:

```
<CDLL 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GoldMine\gm7s32.dll', handle 10000000 at 0x3f44280>
```

however, the _handle for the object is: 268435456.

I'm no expert in ctypes, but I assume 100000000 is the invalid handle, but I would expect that to agree with the object's _handle. I don't know why this would have changed. I've run it on multiple machines with multiple interpreters before.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. I think switching to windll instead of cdll did the trick. Still no idea why it had been working and then stopped, though, so if anyone cares to offer a theory, go for it.

```
gmAPI = windll.LoadLibrary(
    'C:/Program Files (x86)/GoldMine/gm7s32.dll')
recid = create_string_buffer(16)
gmAPI.GMW_NewRecID(recid, username)
```